# What should be done about outdated accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Here is my answer from a while back: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1059/307, the answer no longer has value, since the youtube content it is pointing to has been removed. I tried deleting the answer, but I couldn't since it is an accepted answer.

I don't see a way to salvage this answer, what should be done about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for wanting to keep the site up to date!
♦ moderators can delete accepted answers (I just did) so all you need to do is to raise a moderator flag on your post. Opening a meta question, like you did, works too.

Sometimes, an answer heavily depending on a now-broken link can be salvaged by the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) or [Archive Today](https://archive.is), but not this one.